# Win10: How to reset file history (while keeping configuration)

Tags: windows-10, backup, file-history

I would like to remove all the File History version saved (even the last one) and start it over. I have tried doing it by turning File history off and clicking on "Stop using this drive" (in  `Settings -> Update & Security -> Backup -> More Options`) but then starting over but then my custom configuration (folder included/excluded) is also reset. I have spend a lot of time removing the defaults folders and adding the one I want to backup, so how to reset file history (while keeping configuration)?

Answer (score 5):

This is what I ended up doing

1. Make a copy of your current configuration on `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\FileHistory\Configuration\Config1.xml` (config1.xml and config2.xml are identical)
2. Go to `Settings -> Update & Security -> Backup`, click on Turn off
3. Click on  `More options`, click on Stop using this drive
4. Go to your FileHistory folder and delete all the content.
5. Right-click on your FileHistory folder and select properties,
   sharing tab and copy the path under Network Path
6. Go to `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\File History` (or run
   Filehistory)
7. Click on select drive, add drive and paste the path and click ok
   twice
8. Then click on turn on. As soon as you see “File history is saving
   copies…” (just below the picture of the drive) click on stop. (it
   could take a few seconds or as long as 1 or 2 minutes).
9. Open the 2 .xml in
   `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\FileHistory\Configuration`
   and the 2.xml in your FileHisory folder under
   `\USER\COMPUTER\Configuration`.
10. For each of the 4 .xml, delete verything below the userID
11. Open your backup config in step 1 and copy everything below the
     userID and copy it in the 4 .xml mentionned abovee
12. Go to `Settings -> Update & Security -> Backup` and click on more
     option. You should see your config there. If yes, click on Backup
     now